# My 1992 Geo metro w/auto transmission does not shift automatically, but works fine shifting manually

Tags: automatic-transmission, manual-transmission, shifting, geo

My 1992 Geo metro with automatic transmission does not shift automatically, but it works fine shifting manually.  The transmission shop check says the transmission is fine.

Comment: Go to a different tranny shop ... best advice I can give you.

Comment: so if you put it in drive and hit the gas lightly, it will just hold first and not shift into second?

Answer (score 1):

That transmission stores codes for troubleshooting purposes. I suggest you get the codes read first to see if this helps diagnose the issue.

This is a complicated transmission to diagnose, I suggest you find a competent transmission shop.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]